# complicate regexp with optional patterns

Tags: php, regex, string

Good day.
I have a problem with a regular expression, I'm really stuck, the problem is that the field I'm trying to extract could be composed like:

```
NULL

Name#Size^Value#XXL^Quantity#3

Name#Size^Value#S^Name#Color^Value#Black^Quantity#2
```

The size will be always the first, color (optional) the second value, quantity the last.
of course I would like to obtain those values to insert them in a database.

actually I have done this:

```
$txt='Name#Size^Value#S^Name#Color^Value#Black^Quantity#2';

  $re1='(Name#Size\\^Value#)';  
  $re2='((?:[a-z][a-z0-9_]*))'; 
  $re3='(\\^Name#Color\\^Value#)';  
  $re4='((?:[a-z][a-z0-9_]*))';
  $re5='(\\^Quantity#)';    
  $re6='(\\d+)';    

  if ($c=preg_match_all ("/".$re1.$re2.$re3.$re4.$re5.$re6."/is", $txt, $matches))
  {
      $word1=$matches[1][0];      
      $var1=$matches[2][0];
      $word2=$matches[3][0];
      $var2=$matches[4][0];
      $word3=$matches[5][0];
      $int1=$matches[6][0];
      print "<br> Size: $var1 <br> Color: $var2 <br> Quantity: $int1";
  }
```

but i'm not sure on how I can match the color as optional (and in that case take the quantity as second parameter.

Anyone could help me in this?
It should be all wrong.. in that case, please point me in the good direction.

Comment: Why do *Size* and *Color* each have a `Name` and a `Value` field, but *Quantity* does not?

Comment: that's one of the problems, I have any control on the string itself, and is build in this strange way :/

Comment: See my answer for an easy way to not use a complicated regexp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to do this with regex. You can solve it easily by splitting the string twice based on some rules.

Update: Here's the php code. Will work without a single regular expression, also for more complex combinations of these properties.

```
function split_string($string) {
  $properties = Array();
  $pairs = explode('^', $string);
  while ($pairs) {
    $first_pair = split('#', array_shift($pairs));
    if ($first_pair[0] == 'Name') {
      $second_pair = split('#', array_shift($pairs));
      $properties[$first_pair[1]] = $second_pair[1];
    } else {
      $properties[$first_pair[0]] = $first_pair[1];
    }
  }
  return $properties;
}

print_r(split_string("Name#Size^Value#S^Name#Color^Value#Black^Quantity#2"));
print_r(split_string("Name#Size^Value#XXL^Quantity#3"));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [Size] => S
    [Color] => Black
    [Quantity] => 2
)
Array
(
    [Size] => XXL
    [Quantity] => 3
)
```

Comment: I wrote this in Perl and translated to PHP literally. Maybe this could be made more elegant with PHP idioms that I don't know.

Comment: really nice approach i indeed give it a look (and test) thanks! :D

Answer (score 2):

Add ? in the end of the regexp of the color to match the color optionally

Comment: like: (\\^Name#Color\\^Value#?)

Comment: That would only make the last `#` optional. You need it outside of the parenthesis. `(foo)?`.

Answer (score 2):

What about something drastically simpler like this:

```
(?:name#(\w+?)\^)?(?:value#(\w+?)\^)?(?:quantity#(\d+?))?
```

http://regex101.com/r/nN4yT3

Since your last bit (Quantity) doesn't follow the pattern, it ends up a bit goofy in the second capture group; in that respect, it might be easier to use named capture groups:

```
(?:name#(?<name>\w+?)\^)?(?:value#(?<value>\w+?)\^)?(?:quantity#(?<quantity>\d+?))?
```

Comment: I have to test it, sounds really more simple, but i never used the <groups> before...

Comment: If you go the <group> route, you can reference them by name `$matches['name']`.

Comment: really usefull, like it

Answer (score 0):

Just need the optional quantifier (as others say).
But, it might be maintained better as -
(note - am not a php guru)

```
$re =
'/
     Name\#Size\^Value\#
     ( [a-z] [a-z0-9_]* )               # (1)
     \^Name\#Color\^Value\#
     ( [a-z] [a-z0-9_]* )?              # (2)
     \^Quantity\#
     ( \d+ )                            # (3)
/xi';

if ( preg_match_all ( $re, $txt, $matches ))
{
      $var1 = $matches[1][0];
      $var2 = $matches[2][0];
      $var3 = $matches[3][0];
      print "<br> Size: $var1 <br> Color: $var2 <br> Quantity: $var3";
}
```